# Lightroom: Combining previously imported raw and jpeg files to become a single raw+jpeg

Tags: lightroom

So initially I used to treat jpeg and raw files as separate files where the option shown in the image would be checked. After realizing this is not particularly an effective way of importing images, I changed it.

But now I have old photo sets that I want to convert to the new way of doing things, where I would have a raw+jpeg image. I removed the separate jpeg and raw images, and attempted to reimport them with the new settings, but it's not working, any tips?

[image]

Comment: Reimporting from where?

Comment: @FarO. I removed the photos from the catalog without deleting the images, then reimported them using "add". I hope this clarifies my question

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would try moving them to another folder and to import them again. If you see XMP files, maybe try to delete or move them to a separate folder.

Comment: By default I have always imported both and displayed as one. But for some reason, Lightroom occasionally doesn’t combine them (no, I have changed any settings) and it’s annoying. It’s usually with my Fuji XT files, and not consistently.

Answer (score 2):

For Adobe Lightroom to combine a single image jpeg and raw files, the names have to be the same. Usually that is the case out of the camera. In my case, I had imported these files awhile ago, and the jpeg and raw file of the same image had different names.

So I simply renamed all of images, jpeg and raw, using YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond naming scheme. Removed them from the catalog, then reimported them making sure that in the preferences, the option of "Treating JPEG files next to raw files as separate photos" is unchecked. Now I have what I want, a single raw+JPEG file for each image in Lightroom.